# How does RIP (Routing Information Protocol) work?

Tags: networking, routing, routing-table

Here is a network scenario:

[image: Capture.png] network scenario:

All the mentioned routers have RIP Ver 2 running and below is their routing table.

```
Router1:
    C    1.0.0.0/8 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
    R    2.0.0.0/8 [120/1] via 10.0.0.2, 00:00:26, Serial2/0
    R    3.0.0.0/8 [120/2] via 10.0.0.2, 00:00:26, Serial2/0
         10.0.0.0/30 is subnetted, 2 subnets
    C    10.0.0.0 is directly connected, Serial2/0
    R    10.0.0.4 [120/1] via 10.0.0.2, 00:00:26, Serial2/0

Router2:
    R    1.0.0.0/8 [120/1] via 10.0.0.1, 00:00:11, Serial2/0
    C    2.0.0.0/8 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
    R    3.0.0.0/8 [120/1] via 10.0.0.6, 00:00:15, Serial3/0
         10.0.0.0/30 is subnetted, 2 subnets
    C    10.0.0.0 is directly connected, Serial2/0
    C    10.0.0.4 is directly connected, Serial3/0

Router3:
    R    1.0.0.0/8 [120/2] via 10.0.0.5, 00:00:26, Serial2/0
    R    2.0.0.0/8 [120/1] via 10.0.0.5, 00:00:26, Serial2/0
    C    3.0.0.0/8 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
         10.0.0.0/30 is subnetted, 2 subnets
    R    10.0.0.0 [120/1] via 10.0.0.5, 00:00:26, Serial2/0
    C    10.0.0.4 is directly connected, Serial2/0

Router4:
    R    1.0.0.0/8 [120/2] via 2.0.0.1, 00:00:26, FastEthernet0/0
    C    2.0.0.0/8 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
    R    3.0.0.0/8 [120/2] via 2.0.0.1, 00:00:26, FastEthernet0/0
    R    10.0.0.0/8 [120/1] via 2.0.0.1, 00:00:26, FastEthernet0/0
```

Having looked at Router4's routing table, we see that it doesn't have the 10.0.0.4/30 network listed in its routing table but it's able to successfully reach 10.0.0.4/30 or anything beyond that network.

Why is the 10.0.0.4/30 network not listed, whereas 10.0.0.0/30 is listed? I understand that 10.0.0.4/30 is available via 2.0.0.1 and can reach 10.0.0.4/30 and beyond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is the 10.0.0.4/30 network not listed, whereas 10.0.0.0/30 is
>   listed?

It is actually the `10.0.0.0/8` network which is listed in the routing table. The `10.0.0.4/30` network is a subnet of the `10.0.0.0/8` network, so anything going to the `10.0.0.4/30` network will match the routing table entry for the `10.0.0.0/8` network.

It looks like the error you made is not using the `no auto-summary` command for the `router rip`. This is a common rookie mistake. You used `version 2` in order to get away from the version 1 classful routing, but you didn't tell it to do that.